# Is possible to have ''two VS in one"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is possible to have two Visual Studio code editors in technical one?

e.g I work with VueJS and ReactJS, but I don't like to use them both in one editor.
Before, I use them in two different (e.g Atom and VS) 
But I want to use Visual Studio Code for them both?

Is possible to install two "faces" of VS, one for one plugin, two for other, independent of each other, have special settings and do not threaten one another?

Have a nice day.

Comment: There are a few ways to solve this, would you be against having to copy a text file with your default settings to each new project you create?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, ya, I can do that, but I wanna, some ''easiest'' way, have two profiles.